# Ansible docker_image_info returns empty list when inspecting image on remote registry

Tags: ansible, docker-registry

I have part of a ansible playbook as follows:

```
  - name: Log into GitHub
    docker_login:
      registry_url: "ghcr.io/v2/"
      username: "{{ github_user }}"
      password: "{{ github_token }}"

  - name: Check requested image exists
    docker_image_info:
      name: "{{ image_name }}"
    register: result

  - name: Output image info
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

Example `image_name = "ghcr.io/company/name:tag"`. When executing `docker manifest inspect ghcr.io/company/name:tag` on a host it returns valid info, but not by ansible role.

Ansible always returns empty list of images:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "images": []
}
```

It looks like it doesn't attempt to connect to a remote registry (at least by execution time). I don't understand how to debug it and do I missing something?

UPDATE: Seems like `docker_image_info` can't get info from remote registry, meanwhile `docker_image` can pull from remote.